# Can a game of chess go on forever?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, game-theory, algorithmic-game-theory, infinite-games

Is there non-terminating game of chess? I ran into this problem while designing a machine learning model to estimate the probability that a given chess player wins. If we ignore the 50-move-rule and any other repetition clauses, could a chess game diverge?

If both players have infinite knowledge and the goal of continuing the game indefinitely, is this possible? I do not know enough game theory to reach a conclusive answer on this. Could we even use Nash-equilibrium theory to model this?

If we considered the statement "from this point in the game, it is possible to play perfectly to avoid a stalemate" as a draw, would this enable us to view this as a finite game?

Comment: Does a perpetual check game count as "going on forever"?

Comment: I would say yes. Since it satisfies "from this point/state in the game, it is possible to play perfectly to avoid a stalemate"

Comment: I think I read recently a calculation of the maximum length of a game that *did* observe the usual repetition rules, where pawns were moved only as often as needed to avoid drawing the game. It also assumed players did not request draws until forced to at the 75-move limit. It was somewhere in the neighborhood of $500$ moves (don't quote me on that). Maybe that gives you an answer? It's not clear to me exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: This is interesting. I am wondering if there is a way to prove that there is an upper bound for the length of a game, with moves as the metric by following the repetition rules, but not being forced to draw after a certain number of moves. If there is an upper bound here, ignoring both sets of rules—is there a global upper bound–but it seems like there is not, given that perpetual check is a thing.

Comment: @Soumik Mukherjee - Thanks for the hint.

Comment: What if both end up with just their king?

Answer (score 1):

The rules of modern chess are designed to terminate any game. Especially the threefold repetition rule, the 50 (75 sometimes ?) moves rule and the draw for insufficient material rule allow this. The rules developed over time. One worldchampion (I have Steinitz in mind) even proved mathematically that with an old rule set there was an infinite game so they formulated a stronger threefold repetition rule.

Therefore ignoring one of the rules definitely allows an infinite game. For an example you can take the perpetual check from the comments.

Comment: There was a 75 move rule for some endgames , but as far as I know this does not hold anymore. It has been determined which is the longest possible game , but this is not very interesting. That the 50 move rule gives such an upper bound is clear.

Comment: @Peter There is need to for 50 moves three fold repetition is enough.

Comment: @Shinrin-Yoku True, this would also give an upper bound , but of course a much much higher one.

Comment: @Peter Yes, but 3 fold repetition came historically earlier than 50/75 moves.

Comment: Ignoring only one of the rules does not allow an infinite game. The 50/75 move rule and the 3 fold repetition both alone guarantee a finite game.

Comment: I searched on Google and found that it was not Steinitz who proved that, it was proven by Morse and Hedlund. Check [This](https://mathshistory.st-andrews.ac.uk/Projects/MacQuarrie/chapter-4/) and [this](https://doi.org/10.1215/S0012-7094-44-01101-4)